# How do I set up a windows NFS server to serve my media to RaspBMC [tutorial]

Tags: networking, raspbmc, setup, windows, nfs

Following on from my woes at trying to use Samba to share media from my windows machine ([SMB performance issues on Raspbmc](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/4483/smb-performance-issues-on-raspbmc)) i thought i'd try (and share) my knowledge of getting my Windows XP Pro Machine running as an NFS server instead.

There has probably been many variations on doing this, but i hadn't seen one that matched my setup, a setup that i feel many people still have.

**XP Pro server**

> Spec : Pentium IV 3.4Ghz 4GB ram, 500Gb Sata-II drive, edimax wireless PCI card.
>
> IP : 192.168.1.40
>
> Location : Attic

**Raspberry Pi**

> RaspBmc - Nightly build 12/1/2013
>
> External Powered USB Hub with : Logitech K260 Wireless Key/mouse & TP Link WN823N Wireless USB & Bluetooth USB.
>
> IP : 192.168.1.100
>
> Location : Living room

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**How I did it**

**INSTALLING NFS**

http://technonstop.com/tutorial-setup-nfs-server-windows

Followed the instructions from several websites.

1) Firstly, Grab the "Services for unix for windows" from : http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=274

2) Do a custom install, selecting **only**

- NFS -> Server for NFS
- Authentication tools for NFS -> User Name Mapping
- Authentication tools for NFS -> User Name Server for NFS
  authentication

3) During install select the behaviour to Case Sensitive

4) Next, select Local User Mapping Server -> Password and group files

*-- My addition*
The next stage asks you to upload passwd and group files, I simply created 2 files on the XP desktop. From this post : http://www.networkedmediatank.com/showthread.php?tid=1434&pid=460253#pid460253 I modified the passwd/group files

*passwd*

```
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/sh
pi:x:1000:1000:pi:/home/pi:/bin/sh
```

*group*

```
root:x:0:
pi:x:1000:
```

to represent the Raspberry pi user.

5) Once the installation was complete, go `start -> windows services for unix -> services for unix administration`

6) select `User Name Mapping` on the left, and then the `maps` option on the right. I didn't select Simple maps, and decided to use advanced maps

*Show User Maps*

click `list windows users` and `list unix users`. from windows select `Administrator` from unix select `pi` then click `add` ignoring the warning about administrator special account

*Show Group Maps*

click `list windows groups` and `list unix groups`. from windows select `Administrators` from unix select `pi` then click `add`

Then `apply` in the top right.

**Setting up shares**

1) For each of my shares `E:\music` and `E:\movies` i right clicked on the folders in windows explorer, selected `sharing and security` and then the `NFS Sharing` tab.

2) Within the tab I created the share names `music` and `movies` with an encoding of ANSI, *unchecking* anonymous access

3) Within the permissions button, i *unchecked* `Allow root access` and selected `Read/Wite` as the type of access

4) Ok'd all this

5) Within /etc/fstab on the raspberry pi (via PuTTy) `sudo nano /etc/fstab` I added the following lines:

```
192.168.1.40:/music /home/pi/music  nfs defaults,user,auto,noatime,intr 0   0
192.168.1.40:/movies    /home/pi/movies nfs defaults,user,auto,noatime,intr 0   0
```

(obviously after creating the relevant directories within /home/pi)

**Firewall setup**

Unfortunately the initial firewall port opening specified in the bottom of this post : http://www.networkedmediatank.com/showthread.php?tid=1434&pid=460252#pid460252 didn't appear to work for me, however (shock) microsoft was on hand to offer that perhaps I should try and open some other ports too.

```
User Name Mapping and Server for NFS    Portmapper                  TCP, UDP        111
Server for NFS                          Network Status Manager      TCP, UDP        1039
Server for NFS                          Network Lock Manager        TCP, UDP        1047
Server for NFS                          NFS Mount                   TCP, UDP        1048
Server for NFS                          Network File System         TCP, UDP        2049
```

(from http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753302(v=ws.10).aspx )

**DONE!**
I added the new mounts as sources in both music and movies, and they appear much much more responsive than samba

Comment: Only difference I was on Windows 8 a laptop, had to use Oracle VirtualBox with FreeNAS http://www.freenas.org/ using the BridgeAdapter on the VB, had to add another Virtual Hard Drive as Storage (8GB fixed). only had to switch on NFS/FTP in Unix(mode) Raspberry Pi picked up the NFS share instantly (using Raspbmc)

Comment: Unfortuntely Unix Services for Windows does not run on the x64  Version of Windows 7 Professional

Answer (score 0):

This is peachy for WinXP, but less good for other versions of Windows, which MS explicitly say their "services for Unix" won't work with.

FreeNFS doesn't work for me (reasons still TBD), and others are paid-for.  The only free Windows NFS server I've found which works is on CodeProject.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/309936/Csharp-NET-Network-File-System-NFS-Server?msg=4719043#xx4719043xx

I've got some improvements to this (most importantly setting a "virtual root" so that you don't have to expose your whole C: drive) which hopefully will get rolled back into his codebase.  It's not the prettiest code ever, and there are definitely ways its performance can be improved, but it does the job perfectly well for mounting a root filesystem.