# Samba Server not running

Tags: raspbmc, filesystem, samba

I have installed XBMC on my Raspberry Pi (RaspBMC). I have an external HDD connected via USB to my raspberry Pi, which I would like all of my movie content on. Logging into the Raspberry Pi using an SSH, I installed and configured Samba Server using the following guide (All the text is commands used is specified in the Video-notes):

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jr2Jz8km2BU

This succesfully got me a setup where my Raspberry Pi was running as a Media Center while allowing me to Map the external content disk to my laptop. However, as it was running NTFS the transferspeed was only ~2.2MB/s. So I formatted my drive into a ext4-filesystem. XBMC is accepting the new filesystem fine, but for some reason I suddently have problems with Samba Server. When I get the status of Samba Server, the smbd deamon is not running. And even as I star or restart samba server, it says "smbd running" but isn't running afterwards.

I haven't been able to find any leads on google in this matter, and I have tryed deleting the configuration and remaing it. The folder on the root, which it should map is still there. Any good guesses why me formatting the HDD and then installing a new filesystem is having an effect on Samba Server?

Comment: Is anything interesting logged in `/var/log/syslog` or `/var/log/samba/smbd`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I followed [these](http://www.howtogeek.com/139433/how-to-turn-a-raspberry-pi-into-a-low-power-network-storage-device/) instructions from HowToGeek on how to turn your Raspberry Pi into a low power network storage device.

Those instructions worked perfectly for me, however, I did change the external drive formatting from NTFS to ext4 due to the very high CPU utilization used by ntfs-3g.  I was getting less than 5 MB/s write throughput to the Pi using NTFS.  By switching to ext4 my throughput increased to 10 MB/s write throughput to the Pi.  I still hit 100% CPU utilization on the Pi, but my 100 Mb Ethernet was running close to 80 % utilization so I figured that this was going to be as good as it gets on the existing Pi hardware.

I also use two external USB drives as the article suggests and use rsync to copy from the primary drive to the backup drive.  I get about 5 MB/sec throughput when copying data from one external drive to the other.

Answer (score 0):

Have you had a look at my tutorial that I posted on here?

[How do I set up a windows NFS server to serve my media to RaspBMC [tutorial]](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/4536/how-do-i-set-up-a-windows-nfs-server-to-serve-my-media-to-raspbmc-tutorial)

I managed to get this (NFS) working well after I had had difficulty getting samba to work
(see [SMB performance issues on Raspbmc](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/4483/smb-performance-issues-on-raspbmc) )

Comment: This isn't exactly the solution I am looking for. I don't want to share files from PC to my Raspberry. I wan't the HDD which is connected to my Raspberry to share with the PC.

Comment: @Orpedo ok, i mis-interpreted the question.